# Exporting data from ontology - Protege

Tags: export, sparql, ontology, protege, dlquery

How to export data from ontology to an excel sheet using Protege.
For example, I want to get a table with 2 columns:
Class rdf:ID, Super Class rdf:ID.

Comment: There was some export as CSV functionality in earlier versions of Protege, but I don't think that it still does exist (http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Queries_and_Export_Tab). But maybe I'm wrong. I'd suggest Jena + SPARQL as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved!..
From the tap SPARQL Query
type the query:

```
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }
```

then execute and copy the result directly into an excel sheet :)

Comment: In case you want to exclude `owl:depricated "true"`, you can do that with a filter.